# electron-forge @maker-dmg how to change icon positions in the dmg installer

Tags: macos, electron, dmg, electron-forge

I have been trying to modify some parameters in the `maker-dmg`, so far I got all I wanted but the icon position.

this is what I have at the moment:

```
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-dmg",
      config: {
        title: "Gallery",
        background: "src/assets/installer-assets/installBackground.png",
        format: "ULFO",
        icon: "src/assets/installer-assets/brand-icon.icns",
        contents: [
          { x: 192, y: 344, type: "file", path: "Gallery.app" },
          { x: 428, y: 344, type: "link", path: "/Applications" }
        ]
      }
```

but I am getting an error saying it can't find the Gallery.app.

> An error occured while making for target: dmg
> "Gallery.app" not found at: /var/folders/07/rvgsd3wx7_949217htsn84pw0000gn/T/Gallery.app

I know that the maker only forwards information to the [appdmg](https://github.com/LinusU/node-appdmg) library.
I have been going through their documentation, all I found is that all are treated as relative paths.

Basically I don't know what is the temporary mounting location, I only wanted to specify the x and y variables from the content object, but it forces me to specify type and path.

Has anyone changed the dmg style before? Please any help is highly appreciated.

PD. this works when I mount a dmg before without specify content and then I add content like:

```
{ x: 192, y: 344, type: "file", path: "/Volumes/Gallery/Gallery.app" },
```

But once I eject it and update the forge config to include the above line It breaks.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone going through the same bs, just used `process.cwd()`.

See example:

```
contents: [
      {
        x: 192,
        y: 240,
        type: "file",
        path: `${process.cwd()}/out/Gallery-darwin-x64/Gallery.app`
      },
      { x: 466, y: 240, type: "link", path: "/Applications" }
    ]
```

and I can finally play around with icon positions! Happy coding.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for this. If you're building for different architectures in 2024 (e.g. Intel (x64) and M1 (arm64)) you can detect those, too:
"path": `${process.cwd()}/out/YOURAPPNAME-darwin-${os.arch()}/YOURAPPNAME.app`
Just remember to include const os = require('os'); at the top of your file